# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence., changing data of a vector through iterations

Tags: python, scientific-computing

When running the following code

```
 for i in range(length):  ##collision
     g[i]=0.25*np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t)
     g_eq[i]=g[i]+g[i]*((g1-g3)*c_alph[0,i]+(g2-g4)*c_alph[1,i])
     g_coll[i]=g[i]-1/tau*(g[i]-g_eq[i])
```

I get a ValueError:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Basically im trying to compute values through a "vectorish" configuration, but cant seem to figure out really well how python works in this way. The idea is create a vector g[i] in order to compute the values g_eq[i] and g_coll[i] within the same cicle.

Comment: What do you think is `c_alph[0,i] `? (answer: an error, since a pair `0,i` cannot be an index). Are you trying to rewrite Fortran (or some other language where 2D arrays are indexed like this) code in Python?

Comment: @Błotosmętek is some kind of vector and matrix calculation, i have a strong base in matlab and trying to extrapolate the knowledge to python, but not working so well, im not able to get the right functions for this.
Plus, c_alph is a matrix of 4x2

Comment: So, if c_alph is twodimensional, you should index it like this: `c_alph[0][i]`